# Meteor handsontables render in collapsible issue.

Tags: meteor, handsontable

Hi there i am trying to put handsomtable in materialize collapsible divs but they render all completely wrong like so

[image]

As you can see the tables are over lapped. But when i click into the tables they fix them self's like so .

[image]

Here is where i load the tables

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header" id="global"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Global What Ifs</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            {{>GlobalWhatIf}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Vat Details</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            {{>Vat}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Bank</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            {{>Bank}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Dividends</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            {{>Dividends tName="Dividends"}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Corporation Tax</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            {{>Dividends tName="CorpTax"}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I was thinking of loading the table templates within each drop down div and rendering them when the header is active but i can get seem to get that working either any idea why this happens thanks

Comment: Can you try wrapping the tables with a ```table-responsive``` class? I'm not sure if it's going to help this scenario, but please give that a shot.

Comment: @blueren Thanks for the reply still no luck tho.

Comment: This looks more like a styling issue than a meteor issue. can u please get your current working code on to jsfiddle?